# Why does DSolve give 1/0 on this first-order Riccati ODE?

Tags: differential-equations

This is from a textbook.

Why does `DSolve` give `1/0` using Mathematica v13.0.1 on Windows 10? Does it happen using other versions? I only have access to 13.0.1 now.

```
ClearAll[y, mu, x, lambda, a, b]
ode = y'[x] ==   a*Exp[mu*x]*y[x]^2 + lambda*y[x] - a*b^2*Exp[(mu + 2*lambda)*x]
DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution should be according to Maple 2022:

```
restart;
ode:=diff(y(x),x)=a*exp(mu*x)*y(x)^2+lambda*y(x)-a*b^2*exp((mu+2*lambda)*x)
sol:=dsolve(ode)
```

gives

```
y(x) = -b*(_C1*sinh(1/(lambda+mu)*a*b*exp(x*(lambda+mu)))+cosh(1/(lambda+mu)*a*
b*exp(x*(lambda+mu))))/(_C1*cosh(1/(lambda+mu)*a*b*exp(x*(lambda+mu)))+sinh(1/(
lambda+mu)*a*b*exp(x*(lambda+mu))))*exp(x*(lambda+mu)-mu*x)
```

In Latex:

$$
y \left(x \right) =
-\frac{b \left(c_1 \sinh \left(\frac{a b \,{\mathrm e}^{x \left(\lambda +\mu \right)}}{\lambda +\mu}\right)+\cosh \left(\frac{a b \,{\mathrm e}^{x \left(\lambda +\mu \right)}}{\lambda +\mu}\right)\right) {\mathrm e}^{x \left(\lambda +\mu \right)-\mu  x}}{c_1 \cosh \left(\frac{a b \,{\mathrm e}^{x \left(\lambda +\mu \right)}}{\lambda +\mu}\right)+\sinh  \left(\frac{a b \,{\mathrm e}^{x \left(\lambda +\mu \right)}}{\lambda +\mu}\right)}
$$

Comment: The same situation arises in `V12.0.0`

Comment: Thanks to all the answers. both are useful. I wish I can accept both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's a bug. The point of this answer is to show how the bug arises and how `DSolve` could have avoided it.  The problem is a Riccati equation and not particularly hard to solve by hand, despite all the parameters. After some spelunking I discovered the `1/0` issue had to do with the coefficients of the auxiliary 2nd-order linear equation associated with the Riccati equation `ode`. If you set `` DSolve`print = Print ``, then you get an outline of the analysis of the problem by `DSolve` (clearly this is meant for internal debugging and not for "showing steps" since some steps are missing). We see early on that `DSolve` seems to think it's a Riccati equation for it solves the associated 2nd-order auxiliary ODE:

```
Block[{DSolve`print = Print}, DSolve[ode, y, x]]
```

> ...
>
> ```
> y''[x] == a^2 b^2 E^(mu x + (2 lambda + mu) x) y[x] 
>   + (lambda + mu) y'[x]
> ```
>
> ...

I traced `Power[0, -1]`, the source of the error, with `TraceAbove -> True` and discovered the divide-by-zero came from the denominator in `dsol` (discussed below). The denominator is contructed from the coefficients of the constants of integration in the solution to the auxiliary equation.  The buggy calls may be inspected with this trace:

```
Flatten[
  Quiet@Trace[
    DSolve[ode, y, x],
    _Coefficient,
    TraceInternal -> True]
  ][[-2 ;;]]
```

Here's the outline of how `DSolve` approached the problem, with an adjustment to `Coefficient`:

```
Block[{q0, q1, q2, f, g, h},
 {q0, q1, q2} = Together[CoefficientList[
    -a b^2 E^((2 lambda + mu) x) + lambda y[x] + a E^(mu x) y[x]^2,
    y[x]], Trig -> True];
 dsol2 = DSolve[
    y''[x] == -q0*q2*y[x] + (q1 + D[q2, x]/q2) y'[x],
    y[x], x];
 sol0 = y[x] /. First[dsol2] // ExpandAll;
 (****)
 {f, g, h} = {
   Coefficient[sol0, Sqrt[C[1]]], 
   Coefficient[sol0 /. C[2] -> Log[C[2]], C[2]],
   q2} /. _C -> 1;
 (****)
 dsol = {y[x] -> -((C[1] D[f, x] + D[g, x])/(h (C[1] f + g)))} // 
    Simplify // DSolve`DSolveToPureFunction
 ]

(* InverseFunction::ifun messages omitted...
{y -> Function[{x},
  (b*E^(lambda*x) (E + E^2 C[1] + 
     E^((2 a*b*E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)) C[1]))/
   (E + E^2 C[1] - 
      E^((2 a*b*E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)) C[1])]}
*)
```

The solution is `dsol`:

```
ode /. dsol // Simplify
(*  True  *)
```

The bug arises in the line highlighted with `(****)`.  What `DSolve` does is to try to get the coefficients of the solution `sol0` to the auxiliary equation with the following:

```
Coefficient[sol0, C[1]]
Coefficient[sol0, C[2]]
```

But `sol0` has the form

```
sol0
(*
(E^((a b E^(lambda x + mu x))/(lambda + mu) - C[2]) Sqrt[C[1]])/Sqrt[2] - 
 (E^(-((a b E^(lambda x + mu x))/(lambda + mu)) + C[2]) Sqrt[C[1]])/Sqrt[2]
*)
```

And both calls to `Coefficient[]` yield zero, since `C[1]` and `C[2]` are hidden inside `Sqrt[]` and `E^...` respectively.  This leads to `(C[1] f + g)` being zero in the denominator of `dsol`, which gives the `Power::infy` error.  Constants of integration in linear ODEs (the auxiliary 2nd-order ODE in this case) often end up as an argument of an exponential function, so I would expect some ability of `DSolve` to handle the.  For instance, the following modification yields another way to obtain a solution:

```
{f, g, h} = {
  sol0 /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0}, 
  sol0 /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 1},
  q2}
```

One has to avoid `C[1] -> 0`, so finding a basis for the second-order solution space takes some care.  Similarly, one could use `SeriesCoefficient` or `Series`. Again the `Sqrt[C[1]]` poses a slight problem, since the coefficient one wants is for the `1/2` power, not the linear term.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get a solution, is to solve the ODE for y[x].

```
ode = y'[x] ==
   a*Exp[mu*x]*y[x]^2 + lambda*y[x] - a*b^2*Exp[(mu + 2*lambda)*x];

rule1 = Thread[CoefficientList[ode[[2]], y[x]] -> {r, s, t}]

(*     {-a b^2 E^((2 lambda + mu) x) -> r, lambda -> s, a E^(mu x) -> t} *)

red = Reduce[
  y'[x] == (ode[[2]] /. rule1) && r != 0 && s != 0 && t != 0, y[x]]

(*   t != 0 && (y[x] == (-s - Sqrt[
     s^2 - 4 r t + 4 t Derivative[1][y][x]])/(2 t) ||
   y[x] == (-s + Sqrt[s^2 - 4 r t + 4 t Derivative[1][y][x]])/(2 t)) &&
  r s != 0   *)

ode2 = red[[2, 1]] /. Reverse /@ rule1

ysol1[c1_] = y /. Flatten@DSolve[ode2, y, x] /. C[1] -> c1

(*   Function[{x}, -((
  E^(-mu x) (I a b E^((lambda + mu) x)
       Cosh[(a b E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)] +
     a b E^((lambda + mu) x)
       c1 Sinh[(a b E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)]))/(
  a (c1 Cosh[(a b E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)] +
     I Sinh[(a b E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)])))]   *)
```

This satisfies the ODE. The second part of red yields the same solution.

```
ode /. y -> ysol1[c1] // FullSimplify

(*   True   *)
```

If you want a real solution:

```
ceim = ComplexExpand[Im[ysol1[c1][x]] // FullSimplify,
  TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]

Solve[ceim == 0, c1]

(*   {{c1 -> 0}}   *)

ysol1[0][x] // FullSimplify

(*   -b E^(lambda x) Coth[(a b E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)]   *)
```

A first glance shows how to derive this from the solution [MichealE2 got](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268252/why-dsolve-gives-1-0-on-this-first-order-riccati-ode/268259#268259).

```
yME2 = Function[{x}, (b E^(lambda x) (E^C[2] +
         E^((2 a b E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)) Sqrt[C[1]] +
         E^(2 C[2]) Sqrt[C[1]]))/(E^C[2] -
       E^((2 a b E^((lambda + mu) x))/(lambda + mu)) Sqrt[C[1]] +
       E^(2 C[2]) Sqrt[C[1]])] /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2};

Solve[yME2[x] == ysol1[0][x], {c1, c2}]

(*   Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may

{{c1 -> E^(2 c2)/(-1 + E^(2 c2))^2}}   *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Fyi, this has been fixed in 13.1. Now it does not give 1/0 but gives the correct solution.

The following is screen shot

[image]

Comment: Is V31.3 out yet?

Comment: @MichaelE2 it is on the cloud only.